# Is it possible to transform an XML that does not have fixed structure to an XForms using orbeon?

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I have an XML file that I want to transform to xforms. I know that can be done by submission part of the model if the data is fixed, but my XML file could change, probably meaning that the XML file needs to be parsed.

Can that be done by orbeon?

Answer (score 0):

To only transform the XML file, i would prefer to use `XSLT`. With `Orbeon XForms`, one can take the advantage of creating rich web forms with lot of cool features and save the inputed data in xml format.

With `Orbeon XForms`, you can take an xml file and make that as a model instance and from there you can modify the instance as you wish and later push that instance where ever you want to, it can be a webservice, an external application, a database, etc.

Comment: Thanks. Basically what I want to do is to edit an XML file. So I need XForms as an intermediate form and presentation.

Comment: @sherrielin: If your xml file has only one root node, then YES, you can edit the XML according to your wish.